# How to enable "User must change the password at next logon" when creating a Local user account by c# application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms, user-accounts

I am developing a simple tool for **create local user accounts** on windows and add them to administrator group or guest group.

I just need to know that how to enable the **"User Must Change The Password At Next Logon"** option when creating a new **local user account**. I am using c# , windows form application to write my script. I have used below code to create the user account and set password to Pass@123 and need to enable **"User Must Change The Password At Next Logon"** option.

I have tried to use `NewUser.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0;` but this did not worked, threw an exception since this is used for ActiveDirectory.

Can someone assist me regarding this?

```
try
{
  DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" +
  Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
  DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add(UserID, "user");
  NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "Pass@123" });
  NewUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", "A user account managed by system"});
  NewUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "FullName", "Work From Home: " + UserID });

  NewUser.CommitChanges();
  DirectoryEntry grp;

  grp = AD.Children.Find(AccountType, "group");

  if (grp != null) { grp.Invoke("Add", new object[] { NewUser.Path.ToString() }); }
     MessageBox.Show("Account Created Successfully","Successfull", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
     MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found how to enable **User Must Change Password At Next Logon** in a local user account with c# script

`NewUser.Properties["PasswordExpired"].Value = 1;`

This one worked successfully.

Thank You so much !

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since i had to try to manage a local AD directly from .net code so this might be outdated.

Try: `NewUser.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0] = 0;`

If I'm not mistaken ["pwdLastSet"] is in itself and ICollection :).
Otherwise i would recommend you look into System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement. Then you could simply use `UserPrincipal.Current.ExpirePasswordNow();`

Or something equivalent once you have defined your PrincipalContext. Here is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0
`

Comment: Thank You very much Erik. Really appreciate your feedback. Unfortunately above solution didn't work. And I have found a way to resolve my issue.

Comment: Ok glad to hear that you have resolved your issue! :)